# Turn off the light around iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have code for turning off the light around Youtube iframe, but it only works normally in chrome-browsers.
In Firefox I can turn off the light but I can't turn on it again.
Any idea why in Firefox doesn't work?

code (or https://jsfiddle.net/uhL35f15/):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.video {
position:relative;
z-index:102;
}
#persoff {
background:#000;
opacity:0.9;
filter:alpha(opacity=90);
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:100;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<iframe class="video" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5HLtpoxOeuM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<br><br>

<button class="switch">turn off light</button>
(to turn on light - click somewhere)

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var per = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#persoff").css("height", $(document).height()).hide();
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if(($(event.srcElement||e.srcElement).attr('class') != 'switch') && per == 1) {
      $("#persoff").toggle();
      per = 0;
    }
  });
  $(".switch").click(function(){
    $("#persoff").toggle();
    per += 1;
    if (per == 2) {
      per = 0;
    }
  });
});
</script>

<div id='persoff'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox doesn't use global `event` model, you have to explecitely pass it as hanlder function parameter.

In your case, you are already passing it as `e`. So use `e` not `event` in click handler.

EDIT: in fact in your case, you cannot check for `event.srcElement` as in FF event is `undefined`.

EDIT2: so use instead: `if(!$(e.target).hasClass('switch') && per == 1)`

As a side note, i don't get your logic regarding `per` variable but that's quite off topic.

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: @user25 If `event` is `undefined`, then `event.srcElement` throws an error. Check your console in FF.

Comment: yeah.. it solved the problem) I also was focused `$("#persoff").toggle();` even without clicking somewhere but clicking on the button the second time it has to turn on the light again

Comment: _"don't get your logic regarding per variable"_ because if you click somewhere it turn off the light http://jsfiddle.net/uhL35f15/5/ but it has to turn off the light only by button

Comment: @user25 You could instead toggling a class: http://jsfiddle.net/uhL35f15/6/  But ya, regarding your expected behaviour, then `per` was making sense

Comment: Functionally identical but more conventional and simpler to understand (for me anyway), use `e.stopPropagation()` - https://jsfiddle.net/uhL35f15/7/

Comment: @Roamer-1888 You are correct, that's much readable even if i'd use `hide()` not `toggle(false)` regarding readability